# Nginx load balancer seems to sending domains to wrong upstream randomly

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Having an issue with nginx load balancer, i have two servers with two ports, the api sub domain uses one port and the frontend uses another port, there are two docker containers running in kubernetes with nginx listening on the different ports. So kubernetes has port 30001 forwarding traffic to one pod and 30002 to another pod - both on port 80 internally.

This works fine if i access the node machines via ip on both ports, the correct containers are responding, so i'm seeing the balancer part being the issue. If i access example.com one second it will load the correct upstream and i see the front end, but if i refresh a few times it seems to then use the backend upstream and loads the wrong thing. If i then refresh again, it loads the front end and so on. It's almost like it's picking up the wrong domain before it forwards the request.

Strangely though, the cdn.example.com always forwards to the correct server.

Here is the nginx config of the balancer:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    upstream frontend {
        ip_hash;
        server 192.168.0.2:30001;
        server 192.168.0.3:30001;
    }

    upstream api {
        ip_hash;
        server 192.168.0.2:30002;
        server 192.168.0.3:30002;
    }

    upstream files {
        ip_hash;
        server 192.168.0.5:80;
    }


    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        return 444;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name cdn.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://files;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        }
    }


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the nginx config from the main domain:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include mime.types;
        error_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/error.log;
        access_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/access.log;
    }

}
```

And the api:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.example.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include mime.types;
        error_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/error.log;
        access_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/access.log;
    }

}
```

To make it a bit easier for me to see it happening i disable the backend container, so api.example.com has nowhere to route to, and this then gives 502 Bad Gateway error one second for example.com, then refresh and it loads the correct container then the wrong one.

Here are some error logs from the balancer,

**FRONTEND EXAMPLE.COM**

```
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /styles.4be17988a3897cf4d772.css HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.3:30001/styles.4be17988a3897cf4d772.css", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/calendar.init.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.2:30001/assets/js/calendar.init.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *9 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/calendar.init.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/calendar.init.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *10 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/sparkline.init.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/sparkline.init.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *10 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/datepicker.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/datepicker.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *9 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/morris.init.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/morris.init.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *7 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/sweetalert2.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/sweetalert2.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *9 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/validation.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/validation.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *10 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *6 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/bootstrap-datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/bootstrap-datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *7 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/bootstrap-datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/bootstrap-datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *3 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/emoji/index.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/emoji/index.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *6 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/openvidu/viduapp.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/openvidu/viduapp.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *10 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/emoji.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/emoji.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *9 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/openvidu/openvidu-browser-2.20.0.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/openvidu/openvidu-browser-2.20.0.min.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *7 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *3 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /polyfills-es2015.fef4887586779dfc9d53.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/polyfills-es2015.fef4887586779dfc9d53.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *6 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /scripts.78d9ad3548cc2fd5103e.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/scripts.78d9ad3548cc2fd5103e.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *10 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /main-es2015.ecfc50ab1d577337af7a.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/main-es2015.ecfc50ab1d577337af7a.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *9 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:28:02 [error] 32#32: *3 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js.map HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js.map", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/bootstrap-datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.3:30001/assets/js/bootstrap-datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/emoji.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.2:30001/assets/js/emoji.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *22 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/emoji.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/emoji.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *18 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *22 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /polyfills-es2015.fef4887586779dfc9d53.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/polyfills-es2015.fef4887586779dfc9d53.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *24 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /scripts.78d9ad3548cc2fd5103e.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/scripts.78d9ad3548cc2fd5103e.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *18 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /main-es2015.ecfc50ab1d577337af7a.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/main-es2015.ecfc50ab1d577337af7a.js", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *22 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:42 [error] 32#32: *24 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET /assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js.map HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js.map", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"
2022/05/20 08:29:46 [error] 32#32: *18 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://frontend/", host: "example.com"
```

**BACKEND - API.EXAMPLE.COM**

```
2022/05/20 08:31:55 [error] 32#32: *39 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: api.example.com, request: "OPTIONS /site/home HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.3:30002/site/home", host: "api.example.com", referrer: "http://198.244.200.154:30001/"
2022/05/20 08:33:29 [error] 32#32: *42 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: api.example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.3:30002/index.php", host: "api.example.com"
2022/05/20 08:33:29 [error] 32#32: *42 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: api.example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.2:30002/index.php", host: "api.example.com"
2022/05/20 08:34:22 [error] 32#32: *45 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.130.97.143, server: api.example.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.3:30002/index.php", host: "api.example.com"
```

Could it be somehow related to the internal ip address? When i access via the server public ip addresses directly it connects to it instantly.

Comment: Suggestion: add error and access logs to all server configs, with different names, and re-hit the problematic URL multiple times and gather more details from the Logs and enhance the question here.

Comment: @EngineJanwaar ok will do that